# Search element from array of array in Postgres JSONB

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a table dealers in PostgreSQL. It looks like this:

```
insert into dealers values
  ('{"name":"Henry", "branches":[{"importeurs":[{"akz":"SON",number:"123456"}, {"akz":"ISA",number:"456789"}]}]}'),
  ('{"name":"Mike", "branches":[{"importeurs":[{"akz":"KIN",number:"133232"}, {"akz":"BAB",number:"767676"}]}]}'),
  ('{"name":"Sam", "branches":[{"importeurs":[{"akz":"DOM",number:"125454"}, {"akz":"QEE",number:"565665"}]}]}'),;
```

name column is string and branches column JSONB.

My question is: How to write a select query with given BAB and 767676 to get record Mike?

I tried this

```
SELECT * FROM dealers WHERE branches ->'importeurs' @> '[{"akz": "BAB", "number": "767676"}]';
```

I expected recode Mike back, but it returns nothing.

--------------updated--------------------

In Pic:

1. query returns result
2. query has error  ERROR: operator does not exist: jsonb @? unknown

[image]

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`branches` and `importeurs` are both JSON arrays, so you need to pass an array to the `@>` operator:

```
select *
from dealers
where branches -> 'branches' @> '[{"importeurs": [{"akz": "BAB", "number": "767676"}]}]';
```

Another option is to use a JSON path query:

```
where branches @? '$.branches[*].importeurs[*] ? (@.akz == "BAB" && @."number" == "767676")'
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/f6Yav8hc)

Comment: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ItwG-it_)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank for your response. I tried your queries, first one return nothing, second one has error, please see my update pic

Comment: @J.Z.: both [work for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/f6Yav8hc)

Comment: @J.Z.: if the second throws an error, you are probably using an older Postgres version.

Comment: @J.Z.: yes, Postgres 11 did not have JSON path support (that was introduced in 12)